# Kinetics of three moving particles attached to each other

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, notation

Please refer to the image below. It is a screenshot of page 132, Chapter 13: Kinetics of a Particle: Force and Acceleration of the book Dynamics 14th ed. by R.C. Hibbler. Then refer to my question below.

What exactly does the 32.2 represent? If the resulting forces equal the mass times the acceleration of the mass points minus the friction force [and any other opposing force].

P.S. The solution continues but I've decided not to include it. Please just help me with this part.

[image]

Comment: $g=32.2$ feet per second per second

Comment: @G.Smith thanks! Since I use the book uses the metric system I got confused...